# Can I Masking Input type number in php, but keep the original value when I post the data

Tags: php

I have a problem with masking input type into currency and thousand separator with decimal like " $ 100,000,00 " I found jquery-maskMoney can solve my problem but I need the original integer value like "100000" when I post, so I can easily process it.

This is the example of the Jquery Maskmoney code that I found

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="currency" />
</body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#currency').maskMoney();
})
</script>
```

This code works so well for me, but when I post, I can't get the original value, so the point is, I want to mask the input type with currency and decimal, and I want to POST the original value. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's string replace method when posting.

```
$a = $_POST['currency']
$b = str_replace(',', '', $a );
```

This replaces all $a with nothing, The first parameter is the character you want to replace, and the second is what you want to replace it with.

**EDIT**

Here is the link of the jquery mask money, reading through it gives a lot more options. https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

Also here is i think what you're looking for

[image]

Comment: thankyou for the answer, but the process is not only at php side, i also use ajax to take the value back to the textfield and to post it again to php, so i always use php str_replace, javascript .tolocalestring() all the time, i need something that can make the the visual looks masking, but the value dont, any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Because when posting, str_replace would always help you, If what you're saying is that you are returning it again, what you can do is to str_replace it but always keep a variable for the original value and that's what you return. I can help you more if I can't seem to get the right answer :)

Comment: I have given an updated answer, i read through the user guide and maybe I'll help. If i have you may upvote and mark me as correct :)

Comment: yes thank you. i can use str_replace for ajax return, but unfortunately i have 85% javascript DOM process, you can look at this image https://postimg.org/image/4rcyiswkl/. as you see. when i clicked the "OK" button. i send the record via AJAX, and display the cart to the table below. when i edit record from the table below, the value move to the upper form, it takes so much effort if i always convert currency separator into original value, thats why i need to mask it, without changing the original value, just for our eyes. just a visual, and i stuck. :)

Comment: Okay i'll review it and give my suggestions/solutions again :)

Comment: thankyou  Lorenzo Magno. im waiting for miracle :D :D

Comment: I made my research and I think there is no easy way to do it. You really need to always process it, I know what you mean, visuals do play a big role. But I'm sorry if that's all i can do. You need to mask and unmask everytime, but a function is reusable and would help you write one code for it. Thanks for the upvote, sadly I cannot get the check. Goodluck and maybe i you have time to make a jsfiddle, do make one so we could help you more :)

Comment: No problem!! Anyway, if there is anything else you would like. you can put a comment here and i'll again try my best to help you :)